# Discrete choice model with exclusionary choices

Tags: logit, multinomial-logit, choice-modeling, mlogit

Suppose we have many agents $j\in \{1,..,J\}$ choosing over options $i$ to maximize their outcome of the form
$$ max_i ~~Y_{ij} = \beta x_i + u_{ij} $$

where $u_{ij}$ is an error term.

The options, however, are exclusionary (each one can only be taken by one agent).  Is there a way to think about this problem, particularly to estimate (a) the probability that option $i$ is taken, and (b) the probability that option $i$ is taken by agent $j$?

We can assume there is independence of irrelevant alternatives (IIA) and errors terms can take any shape that is roughly reasonable.

Comment: You mean if agent 1 chooses option 3 that no other agent may choose option 3?

Comment: Yes!  That is correct.

Comment: You need a model to decide what happens if agents 1 and 2 both have option 3 as their favorite.  This is perhaps going to lead to a game-theoretic model.  There is a substantial literature on estimating models of discrete games.  It's not exactly a simple problem, though, and the answer is going to depend on exactly how it is determined who gets what option (i.e. what game is being played).